# Access Build variables inside Pre and Post deployment scripts SSDT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, sqlcmd, database-project, dacpac

I have just set up an SSDT project which I want to use to create local databases on the SQL server hosted locally on my machine.

I want to add some pre- and post- deployment SQL scripts for initialization and cleanups.

Since, the server and the database name can change, I have defined two build variables using the project properties each for the target server and target database.

However, I can't seem to access them inside the post deployment scripts.

The syntax below won't build the project -

```
use [$(TargetDatabaseName)]
```

This builds, but then fails while publishing -

```
use ['$(TargetDatabaseName)']
```

and the error says the ''myTargetDB'' doesn't exist (myTargetDB was passed as a value at the time of publishing)

This might be a trivial thing but I am just not able to get around it. I am on SQL server 2016 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you put both scripts in SQLCMD mode. See the image below surrounding with red.

[image]

Once your target variable is defined, see surrounding with blue in the image above, it can be safely used in the PostDeployment script, see the image below surrounding with blue. 
[image]

If you have any questions, feel free to contact me.

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but it seems that the value "xxxx" is not being overridden by the db name I am providing from within the publish wizard...

Comment: The wizard by default make following four lines :setvar DatabaseName "xxx"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "xxx"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\SQLDatabase\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "C:\SQLDatabase\"
So, there is no need to add extra variable. If you want to add something extra, you should put both scripts ( pre & post ) in SQLCMD mode, as shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

There is a predefined variable, `$(DatabaseName)`, for the name of the target database. You don't need to create your own; and even if you do, you would need to set the same value to both of them.

Not sure about the target server. In most cases, SQL scripts are generated with the assumption that connection to the correct server is already established. Sure, you can change the current server using something like `:connect $(TargetServerName)`, but I think it will only lead to confusion (and I'm not sure it will work, actually).

The only exception I can think of is that you can't use SQLCMD variables to parameterise the logical/physical names of the database files - these have to be hardcoded.

All other variables, if declared in the project properties, should be accessible everywhere. Below is a fragment of a post deploy from one of my projects:

```
use [master];
go

print 'Switching database ownership to sa...';
GO
alter authorization on database::[$(DatabaseName)] to [sa];
go


use [$(DatabaseName)];
go

print 'Creating database master key...';
go

-- Create database master key
create master key encryption by password = '$(DMK_Key)';
go

print 'Running database setup...';
go
exec dbo.init_database;
go
```

---

It is possible, however, that you are trying to reference another database, located on a different server. If that's the case, you need to follow a different approach, namely: built a project for that remote database and add its DACPAC to the list of project references, using the `Add database reference...` menu. There, you will be able to specify variables for both the (linked) server and the database name.

Comment: I was just exploring the idea of somehow being able to insert a row in a table of a different db which is hosted on a different server. Then as per your suggestion, I added the reference using the `.dacpac` file, but again that didn't work...Can you guide me to anything which sort of does that..

Comment: @gkb, for modifying remote data, you need either a linked server, or you can utilise the `openrowset` function. It should be possible to create a linked server during pre- or post-deploy; just make sure your code will test for its existence, or you might end up with lots of duplicates. Either way, you might need to provide remote credentials for the connection, if SSPI is unavailable. Personally, I would probably wrap the entire statement into a dynamic SQL, if it's just a single insert and you don't need to touch the remote system after that.

Comment: Where do you provide the credentials to the remote server? While adding the reference, all it asks for is the server name and the name of the database on that server.

Comment: @gkb, in your custom SQLCMD variables which you can pass through all the way to the `openrowset()` function. If all you need is a single remote insert, I don't think it makes much sense to add external database reference - just wrap it all into a dynamic SQL so that dependency tracker will not throw any warnings or errors about unresolved references. Oh, and put a comment explaining why it was done in such a peculiar manner :)

Comment: There are more than one table that need to be inserted some seed data into, which is based on the newly created db on the local server...basically each db created on the local server will have a corresponding user created (with some other data too) on a single master table and this master table is housed on a different server altogether...

Comment: @gkb, as I have said, in order to reach remote server, you need either a linked server on your local instance, or `openrowset()` with corresponding configuration changes which will allow it (it is disabled by default AFAIK). Try both and see if it works; if not, maybe ask another question, about your specific issue(s).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @Roger..I would probably ask another question to better describe the issue